# Weird GoogleMap zoom animation on Android - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, zooming, google-maps-markers, google-maps-flutter

I am sorry for the question, but I am new to Flutter.

I simply created a Flutter app that shows a map from `GoogleMap`, and then I added a `Marker` to it.
This is the code:

```
class _GoogleMapExampleState extends State<GoogleMapExample> {
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  Set<Marker> markers = {};

  void zoomOnMarker(double lat, double lng) {
    mapController
        .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(lat, lng), 20));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var marker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("123"),
        position: LatLng(45, 9),
        onTap: () {
          zoomOnMarker(45, 9);
        });
    markers.add(marker);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition:
          const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(45, 9), zoom: 5),
      onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
      markers: markers.toSet(),
    );
  }
}
```

As soon as the user taps the marker, `zoomOnMarker` function is called.
The problem is the animation of the zoom ([here the video (I'm sorry for the quality but it's not easy recording from an Android)](https://streamable.com/9x5x35)), the camera moves really weirdly, I'll explain: at first it zooms and only then it moves to the marker. The whole animation results strange.

I spent some hours trying other `CameraUpdate` methods, but with no success.

Is it correct the `zoomOnMarker` function? Are there other ways to to that?
Is there anyone who had the same issue?
Is this animation considered normal?